# Error creating Spark DataSet with array of bytearrays

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm creating a Spark dataset in scala using a case class and the `spark.sql({query}).as[MyCaseClass]` syntax

All is fine until I try to create a dataset with one of my members defined as `Array[Array[Byte]]`

```
case class HbaseRow(
  ip: Array[Array[Byte]]
)

val hbaseDataSet = spark
   .sql("""select ip from test_data""")
   .as[HbaseRow]
```

Normally this works fine but with the array of byte arrays this fails.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.apache.spark.sql.types.BinaryType$ cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.ObjectType
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$arrayClassFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:106)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$arrayClassFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:95)
at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
```

the column is a spark array of IP addresses encoded as byte arrays themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I asked this while stuck but believe I've landed on the solution. Defining my case class type with an Option seems to have done the trick.

```
scala> case class HbaseRow(
 |     ip: Array[Option[Array[Byte]]]
 | )
defined class HbaseRow

scala> df.select($"ip").as[HbaseRow]
res13: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[HbaseRow] = [ip: array<binary>]
```